# check active button when filtering isotope

Tags: jquery, class, filtering, jquery-isotope

so I'm trying to use isotope to filter stuff, and its working... but when i hit the button to filter it doesn't add the class to the active button ".is-checked" and remove it from the last one. Probably just some silly syntax mistake on my part. Can anyone see what's wrong here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>


    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center">Portfolio</h1>
<div class="button-group filter-button-group text-center">
  <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">All</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".metal">Web Design</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".transition">Photography</button>
</div>
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="grid-sizer col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>

            <div class="grid-item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 metal">
                <div class="grid-item-content">
                    <a data-lightbox="test-1" data-title="My caption" href="images/nyc-1.jpg">
                        <img alt="Responsive image" class="img-responsive" src="images/nyc-1.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="grid-item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 transition">
                <div class="grid-item-content">
                    <a data-lightbox="test-1" data-title="My caption" href="images/nyc-2.jpg">
                        <img alt="Responsive image" class="img-responsive" src="images/nyc-2.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="grid-item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 metal">
                <div class="grid-item-content">
                    <a data-lightbox="test-1" data-title="My caption" href="images/nyc-3.jpg">
                        <img alt="Responsive image" class="img-responsive" src="images/nyc-3.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="grid-item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 transition">
                <div class="grid-item-content">
                    <a data-lightbox="test-1" data-title="My caption" href="images/nyc-4.jpeg">
                        <img alt="Responsive image" class="img-responsive" src="images/nyc-4.jpeg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="grid-item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 metal">
                <div class="grid-item-content">
                    <a data-lightbox="test-1" data-title="My caption" href="images/nyc-5.jpeg">
                        <img alt="Responsive image" class="img-responsive" src="images/nyc-5.jpeg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="grid-item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 transition">
                <div class="grid-item-content">
                    <a data-lightbox="test-1" data-title="My caption" href="images/nyc-6.jpg">
                        <img alt="Responsive image" class="img-responsive" src="images/nyc-6.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="grid-item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 metal">
                <div class="grid-item-content">
                    <a data-lightbox="test-1" data-title="My caption" href="images/nyc-7.jpg">
                        <img alt="Responsive image" class="img-responsive" src="images/nyc-7.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="grid-item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 transition">
                <div class="grid-item-content">
                    <a data-lightbox="test-1" data-title="My caption" href="images/nyc-8.jpg">
                        <img alt="Responsive image" class="img-responsive" src="images/nyc-8.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="grid-item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 metal">
                <div class="grid-item-content">
                    <a data-lightbox="test-1" data-title="My caption" href="images/nyc-9.jpg">
                        <img alt="Responsive image" class="img-responsive" src="images/nyc-9.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="grid-item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 transition">
                <div class="grid-item-content">
                    <a data-lightbox="test-1" data-title="My caption" href="images/nyc-10.jpg">
                        <img alt="Responsive image" class="img-responsive" src="images/nyc-10.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="grid-item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 metal">
                <div class="grid-item-content">
                    <a data-lightbox="test-1" data-title="My caption" href="images/nyc-11.jeg">
                        <img alt="Responsive image" class="img-responsive" src="images/nyc-11.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="grid-item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 transition">
                <div class="grid-item-content">
                    <a data-lightbox="test-1" data-title="My caption" href="images/nyc-12.jpg">
                        <img alt="Responsive image" class="img-responsive" src="images/nyc-12.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="images/nyc-2.jpg"></div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/isotope-layout@3.0.1/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/parallax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
    <script>
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
itemSelector: '.grid-item',
percentPosition: true,
masonry: {
columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
 }
});
    $('.filter-button-group').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
$grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue }),$(window).trigger('resize.px.parallax');
});

        function radioButtonGroup( buttonGroup ) {
  buttonGroup.addEventListener( 'click', function( event ) {
    // only work with buttons
    if ( !matchesSelector( event.target, 'button' ) ) {
      return;
    }
    buttonGroup.querySelector('.is-checked').classList.remove('is-checked');
    event.target.classList.add('is-checked');
  });
}

       </script>
```

And my css

```
.grid-item {
    margin-bottom:;
    padding:5px;
}
.parallax-window{
    min-height:300px;
}
.filter-button-group button{

}
.button.is-checked {
  background-color: #28F;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left out part of the code where you needed to define *buttonGroup*:

```
// change is-checked class on buttons
var buttonGroups = document.querySelectorAll('.button-group');
for ( var i=0, len = buttonGroups.length; i < len; i++ ) {
var buttonGroup = buttonGroups[i];
radioButtonGroup( buttonGroup );
}

function radioButtonGroup( buttonGroup ) {
buttonGroup.addEventListener( 'click', function( event ) {
// only work with buttons
if ( !matchesSelector( event.target, 'button' ) ) {
  return;
}
buttonGroup.querySelector('.is-checked').classList.remove('is-checked');
event.target.classList.add('is-checked');
});
}
```